# Save content of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, web-applications, uiwebview

I am working on an app and I need to save the content of UIWebView.

I currently Use        `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"`
to get the html of the UIWebView, but the problem with this method is that it does not save the full content of some webpages.

So my question is **How do you save the full content of a webpage including images and css**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is already a thread about this topic here:

[iphone uiwebview download complete page with CSS and Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720524/iphone-uiwebview-download-complete-page-with-css-and-images)

Hope that helps.