# How to save my home page for offline support in UIWebView

Tags: ios

I have an app that already develop in HTML.
We are rendering app in UIWebview using the server URL.
Everything working fine. But I want to cache the Login page for offline support.

So, If user kill the app and restart the device and open app in offline mode he will see only the blank page.

Is there any way to save the login page so that user will able to see the login page instead of blank page.

Comment: You can make the HTML Page for it & using the web view load that page in Web view.

Comment: Just this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1720548/1545180